# Disable Mosaic Overview Information When Using Identify Tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, mosaic, mosaic-dataset

I have a created mosaic datasets using elevation data. When I add this data to ArcMap and use the identify tool it brings up information about both the footprint and image.

At full extent the identify information under image contains an elevation value and also the name of the overview raster within that location. When I zoom in and identify a location it will bring up the elevation value and the name of the tile with the associated attribute information.

Is there a specific function or property that I need to configure so that the identify tool only provides the elevation value?

[image: IdentifyInfo]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your 'Identify from:' choice is set to Visible, Selectable or All layers in the Identify window. Select the Image layer instead, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

**EDIT**

With mosaic datasets, it's not possible to hide the name of the dataset you're identifying (you can actually do it by right-clicking the name of the dataset under Image in the Identify results, and choose 'Remove from tree', but it will reappear when you identify another location).

An alternative is using the [Pixel Inspector](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000097000000) to identify pixel values, and resize the size of the Pixel Inspector window so it only covers one pixel:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately because an overview is also an image it will also come up under the identify information when image is selected. I have added a screen capture to the OP.